# How to resize text proportionally to browser?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change font-size: according to browser resize text font should change. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried [CSS3 Media Queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) ([browser support](http://www.caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries))?

Answer (score 1):

Prowla's answer works but I find it better to use mediaqueries since it's more light weight, easy to manage and it allows you to adept even more things then just the font-size really easy.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't need to worry about browser support, you can use 'vh', 'vw', or 'vmin'. Chris Coyier has explained it in http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/